# Pasar mas de dos datos en laravel y highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, laravel, highcharts

estoy ejecutando una consulta por laravel para que me traiga un consumo_promedio,y los meses de acuerdo al parametro que le estoy enviando que es el año, al graficarlos en highcharts me los muestra pero quiero que tambn me muestre la sumatoria del numero inicial, hay alguna manera que me muestre esos tres datos en la grafica, quiero que me muestre el consumo_promedio,La suma_inicial y los meses

```
public function report_precebo_anual_consumo_promedio(Request $request)
{

    $collection = Precebo::select(DB::raw('date_format(str_to_date(mes_traslado,"%m") ,"%M") as mes,avg(cons_promedio_ini) as total'))
    ->where('año_destete',[$request->ano])
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('date_format(str_to_date(mes_traslado,"%m"),"%m")'))->get();

    $months = ['January'=>'enero','February'=>'febrero','March'=>'marzo','April'=>'abril','May'=>'mayo','June'=>'junio','July'=>'julio','August'=>'agosto','September'=> 'septiembre','October'=>'octubre','November'=>'noviembre','December'=>'diciembre'];
    $arrayT = [];
    foreach ($collection as $value) {
        $arrayT[] = [$months[$value->mes],$value->total];
    }
    // dd($arrayT);
    return response()->json(['status'=>'success','data'=>$arrayT],200); 
}
```

y esta es la imagen que muestra al graficarla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay alguna manera que tambn me muestre el numero inicial??

les dejare tambn la consulta SQL que hago

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado,"%m") ,"%M") AS mes,
AVG(cons_promedio_ini) AS total FROM formulario_precebo
WHERE año_destete = '2017' GROUP BY mes_traslado ORDER BY 
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado, '%m'), '%m');
```

lo que es mes_traslado y cons_promedio_ini son dos de 30 campos que tiene esa tabla (creo que son 30).

Comment: En si necesitas ayuda con la consulta, o con los datos que ya están en la gráfica.

Comment: no la consulta no por que yo lo hago, pero si necesito los datos para la grafica

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo en base a los valores que tienes en la gráfica. Yo regularmente cuando he tenido que hacer algunos cálculos en la gráfica utilizo la formatter function http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-shared/ para obtener valores y mostrarlos ya sea en las columnas, barras, labels etc. Si eso es lo que buscas te envìo en el link anterior un ejemplo. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: puede ser pero como hago para mostrar varios datos en la grafica, solo muestro uno que es el promedio y quiero tambien mostrar las sumatoria

Comment: Trata de replicar la gráfica que tienes en un snippet para poder ayudarte o en jsfiddle.

Comment: como voy a replicar una grafica que los resultados se generan de una base de datos??